# change css dynamically if condition in PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, dynamic

I'm using a wordpress theme and I do want to change the css of 2 blocks using php when the value of certain variable is even or odd..

this is my code :

```
<?php 
            $i = 0;
            while ( have_posts() ) {

                // Override
                if(($i % 2) == 1) { ?>

                    <style type="text/css">
                        .grid-box-img {
                            width: 54%;
                            float: left;
                        }

                        .entry-head {
                            width: 56%;
                            background-color: #fff;
                            position: absolute;
                            z-index: 10;
                            margin-left: 43%;
                            margin-top: 27%;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php 
                }
                else { ?>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .grid-box-img {
                            width: 54%;
                            float: right;
                        }

                        .entry-head {
                            width: 56%;
                            background-color: #fff;
                            position: absolute;
                            z-index: 10;
                            margin-top: 27%;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                } 
                $i++;
                the_post(); 
            } ?>
```

But, unfortunately it doesn't work... It applies only the CSS of the last value.

How can I do that ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS applies to the whole document (HTML 5 introduces scoped stylesheets, but browser support is weak and they are a terrible solution for this problem).

If you want to indicate that different elements are different then make them members of different classes, don't try to apply different stylesheets to them.

Comment: Thank you. So I oly have to add the value of the variable in the class.. for example : `grid-box-img-12` and then doing the test using the value `12` of the class. Right ?

Comment: You only have two different styles you want to apply, having a "12" seems silly. `class="grid-box-img even"` would seem to make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is that make two classes one for even and other for odd and place a `if` condition where it needed.

```
<a href="/" class="<?php if(($i % 2) == 1){ echo 'even';} else { echo 'odd';} ?> ">Link </a>
```

In your CSS:

```
.even{
//your styling for even class
}
.odd{
    //your styling for odd class
    }
```